# Automatic insert open and close bracket if character over 100

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I would like to perform this function using jquery or javascript. If the text enter by user exceed 100 chars, i would like the javascript to automatic put the open and closing bracket at the text.

For example:

If you purchased or upgraded RegexBuddy after 13 June 2007, you can download the latest version by typing in your email address and RegexBuddy user ID below. If you lost your user ID, type in your email address and leave the user ID field blank. You will then receive an email message with your user ID.

Using javascript:

[If you purchased or upgraded RegexBuddy after 13 June 2007, you can download the latest version by typing in your email address and] [RegexBuddy user ID below. If you lost your user ID, type in your email address and leave the user ID field blank. You will] [then receive an email message with your user ID.]

Can this be achieve? Any help are aprreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple regex-based solution; tweak as you see fit:

```
var s = "If you purchased or upgraded RegexBuddy after 13 June 2007, you can download the latest version by typing in your email address and RegexBuddy user ID below. If you lost your user ID, type in your email address and leave the user ID field blank. You will then receive an email message with your user ID.";

var chunked = s.replace(/(.{1,100})(?:\b|$)/g,'[$1]');
// "[If you purchased or upgraded RegexBuddy after 13 June 2007, you can download the latest version by ][typing in your email address and RegexBuddy user ID below. If you lost your user ID, type in your ][email address and leave the user ID field blank. You will then receive an email message with your ][user ID.]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for something like the below. But it's not bullet proof. I would rather change the event to submit on the form, so that you can be guaranteed it won't mess with what your user is entering, especially on a copy/paste event.

```
<input id="myInput"/>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myInput').keypress(function() {
  var string = $(this).val();
  if (string.length >= 100 && !$(this).hasClass("bracketed")){
    string = "[" + string + "]";
    $(this).val(string);
    $(this).addClass("bracketed");
  }
  // Stripping brackets if delete key is used
  else if (string.length <= 101 && $(this).hasClass("bracketed")){
    string = string.slice(1,100)
    $(this).val(string);
    $(this).removeClass("bracketed");
  }
});
});
```

You can mess with the above solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/DAhq5/